# Does the sum of the reciprocal of the zeros of the zeta converge or diverge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

By zeros of the zeta, I mean b in the complex zero (a + bi).

Does the sum converge or diverge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly *absolutely* divergent: an argument-principle discussion shows that the number of zeros in the critical strip to height $T$ is proportionate to $T\log T$. But if $\rho$ and $1-\rho$ are grouped together (thinking of the functional equation), then that estimate gives convergence of the grouped sum.